# Symfony 3 own global configuration file

Tags: php, symfony, config

How i can create and use own global config with keys/values in symfony?
I was try set keys/values in `parameters.yml` under `parameters` line which been in this file after instalation and get it like `$pageTitle = $this->getParameter('myKey');` and it works but i want own whole config file with structure for ex. `$this->getParameter('myParameters.myKey')` so:

I was created new file:

```
#app/config/myConfig.yml

myParameters:
    myKey: myValue
```

In config.yml i added:

```
#app/config/config.yml

imports:
    - { resource: myConfig.yml }
```

and in controller:

```
$pageTitle = $this->getParameter('myKey');
```

And i have exception:

> FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 118: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "inyconfig" (in....

EDIT

---

This example works but you must do one little change - `myParameters` change to `parameters` and everything is work like a charm.

Comment: give me some feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a dependency injection e.g. BundleNameDependencieInjection related of your bundle and then create Configuration class that provide configure external dependence and/or external configurations

Have a look there http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html#processing-the-configs-array

In parameters you can create some scalar or array variables that can be called in some circumstances in your case you may create an array with some range like that :

```
parameters:
# scalar
   one.two.three:    something 
# array
   oneBis:
      twoBis: 
         threeBis:   somethingBis
```

Comment: Yes i was needed solution like in your (or my) code example but in separate file but with only one change - myParameters -> parameters like you wtritten.

Comment: you have to write parameters instead of myParameters first

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters instead of myParameters.

So, put in app/config/myConfig.yml:

```
parameters:
    myKey: myValue
```

Comment: Same exception: `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "myParameters" (in....`

Comment: Are you sure? I ran the same thing and is working. Are you working on dev environment?

Comment: Yes... If i move `myKey: myValue` to `parameters.yml` under `parameters` - it works but in `config.yml` under `parameters` no... I am on dev enviroment.

Comment: Can you provide also config.yml and parameters.yml? But have you put instead of 'myParameters', 'parameters'?